# Debian 10 Server: Configuring multiple interfaces including computer-to-computer network. Interface does not raise on boot

Tags: linux, debian, networking, network-interface

## Breif

I'm trying to configure a computer-to-computer (via a switch although this isn't directly relevant) network to be used as a high-speed link between my workstation and a server. Both are Debian 10 systems.

## Network Topology

Here is a diagram of my network topology. (Created with http://asciiflow.com/ - might not be secure)

```
          +----------------+
          |                |
          |   ISP Router   |
          |  192.168.0.254 |
          |                |
          +-+------------+-+
            |            |
            |            |
     enp7s0 |            | enp7s0
192.168.0.1 |            | 192.168.0.2
            |            |
+-----------+-+        +-+------+
| WORKSTATION |        | SERVER |
+-----------+-+        +-+------+
            |            |
   enx...   |            | enx...
   10.0.0.1 +------------+ 10.0.0.2
```

## `/etc/network/interfaces` file

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file (same on both systems except the static address)

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/* # this is empty

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp7s0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1/8
#   broadcast 10.255.255.255
#   netmask 255.0.0.0
```

## Status at boot

When I boot either system and check the interfaces using `ip addr`, this is the result

```
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:f0:49:ee:47:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enx...: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ... brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.1/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ...
       valid_lft 85332sec preferred_lft 85332sec
    inet6 ...
```

So it looks like `enp7s0` is not raising at boot. If I run `sudo ifup enp7s0` it comes up with the expected static address, and both computers can communicated via ssh on this link.

What should I do to get this interface to raise on boot?

Comment: It seems to me that your question is actually "How to autmatically bring up an interface on boot on debian based systems". Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `auto enp7s0` to your interfaces file, just like `auto lo` is already there, like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/* # this is empty

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp7s0
iface enp7s0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1/8
#   broadcast 10.255.255.255
#   netmask 255.0.0.0
```

From `man interfaces`:

> Lines  beginning with the word "auto" are used to identify the physical
>          interfaces to be brought up when ifup is run with the -a option.  (This
>          option  is  also  used by the system boot scripts, so interfaces marked
>          "auto" are brought up at boot time.)  Physical interface  names  should
>          follow  the word "auto" on the same line.  There can be multiple "auto"
>          stanzas.  ifup brings the named interfaces up in the order listed.

Comment: Such a simple solution - I should have realized this

Comment: Ok another question then - there is no entry for `enx...blaa blaa`. How does this USB device get automatically raised?

Comment: You can just make an entry for it. The `enx...` prefix indicates that the rest of the interface name is simply the MAC address of the network interface. For USB interfaces, you may want to use `allow-hotplug enx...` instead of/in addition to `auto enx...`: the `auto` keyword tells the system to make one attempt to start the interface at start-up time, while `allow-hotplug` will start the interface any time it is plugged in. It works with non-USB interfaces too.

Comment: You probably have NetworkManager running, and it will probably try at least DHCP to configure the interface if it detects an interface with no configuration and a valid link.